# Is it worth using a HashMap in this instance for speed?

Tags: java, performance, dictionary, hashmap, big-o

I have a function that calls a distance function.  The distance function computes Levenshtein distance algorithm between two input Strings.  I'm trying to find the shortest distance between an inputed word (miss spelleed), and an english word to return (using this as a spellchecker), but I'm not sure if my HashMap is gaining me any ground in speed.  The wordContainer is an array containing n words, does this make my look up time stuck in O(n)?

#### My Code Below

```
  private static String findClosestMatch(String word) {
        Map<Integer, String> wordAndDistanceMap = new HashMap<>();
        wordContainer.forEach(s -> wordAndDistanceMap.put(distance(s, word), s));
        return wordAndDistanceMap.get(Collections.min(wordAndDistanceMap.keySet()));
    }
```

Comment: This is good man, keep using it. You got to access those objects fast which requires the usage of the data structure map.

Comment: But my lookup time is still O(n)?

Comment: You want faster than O(n)?

Comment: O(n) is an acceptable time complexity. The bad one is n^2 and other values which are similar to this. So it is currently fast, do you need a faster method?

Comment: Yes its completely static. I have it initialized outside, as it loads a text file of words into the ArrayList wordContainer when the program starts. It contains a list of dictionary words.  I want to try to get faster than O(n)

Comment: What you probably want is all the words with the lowest distance, but this gives just one. It would be more efficient to use a simple loop.

Comment: @Magnilex it's not `O(n)`. It's hopefully `O(n)`

Comment: Is this true: You have static list of words and you init them, but the comparing word changes right? So your list is static but input is generic? I think you have to index those values.

Comment: Your doubts are justified. The way you use the `HashMap` doesn’t improve anything, it actually makes the code slower. Instead of just remembering the element with the shortest distance, you are putting all calculated values into the map for no benefit, then, you have to iterate the map afterwards to find the actual minimum. So you have added hashing overhead and another iteration instead of reducing the required operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this has a reasonable time complexity it has a lot of over head doing work/creating objects you never need.  I suggest having a simple loop.

```
private static List<String> findClosestMatch(String word) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    List<String> minWords = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : wordContainer) {
        int dist = distance(s, word);
        if (dist < min) {
           min = dist;
           minWords.clear();
        }
        if (dist == min)
           minWords.add(s);
    }
    return minWords;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I had a loop at first - but I'm trying to find a way to spellcheck a word faster than O(n).  Maybe load all words into a tree by length and only search the part of the tree with distance shorter than the inputted misspelled word.

Comment: @Yawn - You have to calculate the Levenshtein distance from `word` to  N other words word, so the search has to be *at least* `O(N)`.

Comment: @Yawn I am sure you could do but you would need a prebuilt data structure.  You could have a dictionary of the the words which start with a given letter (or two) and check the distance for those. This is not the same but usually the first letter is right. What you really need is to convert the word into phonetics and then find the distance.

Comment: @Yawn Most likely your best bet is to build a dictionary/cache of words misspelt and the closest matches (and which words were chosen as a replacement)  You could also return immediately if the word is already a match, rather than brute force checking a word which is already in your dictionary.

Comment: Would finding all permutations of the misspelled work?  Could maybe seek them faster, hm.

Comment: @Yawn it would but you would need an exhaustive list. What you could do is hope that it's one letter off. You could index all the words with one letter missing. Ie bd => bid, bed, bud, bad. This would be O (n) with the number of letters. If this doesn't match try the more exhaustive search.

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate the Levenshtein distance from `word` to N other words.  Calculation the distance N times is O(N).

The only way you can improve on `O(N)` is if you can devise a way to avoid having to calculate the distance `O(N)` times.

The `HashMap` can't help with that.  What you would need to do (and I don't know if this is possible) is devise a way to avoid checking the distance for words that are "a long way away" from `word`.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you need a faster method than this then you have to use an indexing mechanism.

What I can suggest you is [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/). It is an open source and widely used framework to index data. Also, there are some developed versions as [Apache SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) built on the Lucene core. You can read more on the provided links.

After indexing your static list, or indexing the values that you have calculated over them, you can retrieve them in a very short time that you are currently desiring.

I hope this will help.